# How to change $request_uri in nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

We get information from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` not from `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

I want to define `$request_uri` to change `/example` to `/module/controller/action`

not redirect.

I tried code blow to do this but it doesn't work.

```
location /example {
    rewrite /module/controller/action;  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869930/how-to-change-request-uri-in-nginx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need rewrites for this, just `try_files`.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

In this case, nginx will serve static files, and anything else will be passed to `/index.php` for handling.